# How to hide parent folder on URL with htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, directory, hide

I have searched extensively about this problem and haven't been able to find a solution. I'm working locally, so I have this URL:

```
http://localhost/IASON/iasongitlab/static_website/html/solutions.html
```

I have managed to hide the file extension, so now my URL are like this:

```
http://localhost/IASON/iasongitlab/static_website/html/solutions
```

But now I need to hide the /html/ folder from my URL, so that it looks like this:

```
http://localhost/IASON/iasongitlab/static_website/solutions
```

This is just an example. I have multiple views, so I need to code in htaccess to hide the /html/ folder on each view.

This is my htaccess file now:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

I have tried multiple suggestions without success, and would appreciate any insight into solving this problem.

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, could you please try following. Please make ure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^(IASON/iasongitlab/static_website)/(solutions)/?$ $1/html/$2.html [NC,L]
```

---

---

OR in case you don't want to hardcode the path details and look for `solutions` at last in uri then you could try following. Make sure you place either following OR above rules only at a time.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(solutions)/?$ $1/html/$2.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: I put your code, clean cache, but this is what i get:                                                            
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.46 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1g PHP/7.4.11 Server at localhost Port 80

Comment: @GianmarcoMontanari, Also I had edited my rules(only thing I removed condition part and written them in a single rewrite), you could try these edited ones too once and let me know then.

Comment: @GianmarcoMontanari, could you please do let me know if .htaccess file is present in same path where you have folder `IASON`? Kindly confirm once.

Comment: still not working. The htaccess is in the static_website path